# uiautomator not clickable in mac

Tags: android, uiautomatorviewer

Configuration

> OS: macOS Big Sur
> Java: 1.8.0_231
> Android studio: 4.2

I have also set PATH as below

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/x86_64
```

When I open uiautomatorviewer from the terminal, the buttons are not clickable.

**uiautomatorviewer screen for reference**

[image]

Comment: any error in logcat ?

Comment: uiautomatorviewer itself is not showing me any error for example: if the device is not connected then it should throw an error  "no android device detected by ADB" 

The screenshot button itself is not clickable

though I checked in logcat no errors are getting generated

Comment: I have the same problem btw uiautomaterviewer is not working with newer versions of Java.

Comment: More info: https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/911#issuecomment-849389068

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution it worked for me:

Download the latest swt.jar, from https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.html, rename downloaded swt.jar to swt2.jar, copy to Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64/ and to Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86 and run uiaautomatorviewer.

source:
https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/911

Answer (score 1):

Change swt.jar file in Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64/ and tAndroid/sdk/tools/lib/x86.
Download swt.jar file of version 4.20 only.Other versions don't work.